# Laravel migration, set default as empty?

Tags: laravel

Is there anyway to set default value of a table field as ''?

We can set default value of a field as NULL using the below code.

```
$table->string('reason', 32)->default(NULL);
```

Instead of that, i would like to set default of the field as **''** (Empty string).  How can we do that?

Comment: did you try `->default('""')`?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the usefulness of an empty string default vs a null.

Comment: $table->string('reason', 32)->nullable()

Comment: @apokryfos sometimes null values throw errors with some JavaScript libraries.

Answer (score 4):

when you use the `nullable()` default value is `NULL`

```
$table->string('reason',32)->nullable();
```

or

```
$table->string('reason',32)->default(0);
```

Comment: I don't know how this answers his question. He is not looking for NULL but for an empty string

Answer (score 0):

`->nullable()` does not suit my needs or answer his question. Through trial and error, I found that `->default('')` works for me.

**this**

```
Schema::create('contact_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->string('contact_name', 20);
   $table->string('contact_url', 100);
   $table->string('icon')->default('');
   $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
   $table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
});
```

**created this** (notice the nulls are missing from the icon column)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

you just need to set

```
$table->string('reason', 32)->nullable();
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also set value in inside the nullable like this way

```
$table->string('reason',32)->nullable(0);
```

or

```
$table->string('reason',32)->nullable('string as you want');
```